Explicit form of the projection map to a sub-algebra
When considering the the projection map $\pi: V \to V/W$ where $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$, we can, in general, write the action of $\pi$ on $v \in V$ as $\pi(v) = v+W$.
This is useful because it allows us to talk about what an element in the equivalence class defined by $v$ looks like explicitly. However, in the case of an algebra, say a Clifford Algebra for example, which is defined as the quotient of another algebra by an ideal, it is unclear to me if there is a comparably explicit way to write the projection of an element $a \in A$ into the quotient algebra.
Does such a way exist? If a general way does not exist are there certain types of ideals one could quotient an algebra by which would yield an easily definable projection map like that for a quotient vector space?

When you write "the action of $\pi$ on $v \in V$" do you just mean "the image of $v \in V$ under $\pi$? I'm a little bit hung up on the word action here. You're just defining the standard quotient map, right?

Yes, you’re correct. I just got my verbs mixed up. I should have said image. And yes its the standard quotient map.

Let $A$ be an algebra and $I\subset A$ an additive subgroup there.
Let $\pi: A\to A/I$ be quotient map as defined in the context of groups. (As $A$ is abelian $I$ is a normal subgroup).
For the quotient group $A/I$ to be a vector space subset $I$ not only has to be a subgroup it has to be a vector subspace, and the map $\pi$ is the same set theoretically. It gets promoted as a vector space homomorphism (linear transformation).
In the same vein, if further $I$ is an ideal in $A$, the quotient vector space $A/I$ becomes an algebra under obvious operations, and the same map $\pi$ gets double promotion as algebra homomorphism.
